# I got this error in Next.js while implement Pannellum-react to make 3D images "Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules."

Tags: 3d, next.js, pannellum

I can't make 3D images with pannellum in Next.js because I got this error:

[image]

My code:

```
import { Pannellum } from "pannellum-react";
 import myImage from "./images/download1.jpg";

<Pannellum
    width="100%"
    height="500px"
    image={myImage}
    pitch={10}
    yaw={180}
    hfov={110}
    autoLoad
    showZoomCtrl={false}
    onLoad={() => {
      console.log("panorama loaded");
    }}
  >
    <Pannellum.Hotspot
      type="custom"
      pitch={31}
      yaw={150}
      handleClick={(evt, name) => console.log(name)}
      name="hs1"
    />
  </Pannellum>
```

Comment: Do you use `next-transpile-modules` by any chance?

Comment: No, what does this package please cause i didn't hear for this before?

Comment: Hm, then what version of Next.js are you using in your app?

Comment: im using v10.0.4 version of Next

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Hey guys I have this problem also, any solutions? I'm really stuck. :-(